# long-running applications and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, session

I have a web application that accepts an input from the client (browser) and calls an application at the server side with the input. The problem is that the application will run for a long time (about 20s). In order to not block the client (browser) and show the progress to the user, my server side POST function returns immediately and feeds the user 
input to the application. Once the application computed the result, I send the result to the client using socket.io. Another twist to the scenario is that the application can not be repeatedly launched and closed (will cause some problem with CUDA) so the whole server side runs just one instance of the application. A sketch of my server-side code looks like the following. Embedded in the code are the three questions that I have searched through the Internet and tried various solutions but could not work out. Any help on them is really appreciated. If this is not the right place to ask, I would be thankful to any feedback about where to ask this question.

```
var express = require('express');
const{ spawn }= require('child_process');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var darknet = spawn('./darknet', other arguments...) ;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  app.socket = socket;

  console.log('A connection has been established');
})

darknet.stdout.on('data',(data) =>{

    // This function is called once darknet finished computation and wrote the result to the stdout 

   // Question 1: now need to send the data back to the client but have no access to any socket here? 

})

io.on('connection', function(socket){

//Question 2: how to store this socket so that I can use it in a solution to the Question 1? Can I use session? */

//Question 3: I observed that once the client side refreshed its page (for example, uploaded an image), the previous socket will be closed and a new socket will be established. How do I make sure that I send the output from the application to the right socket since the original one may be invalid when the output is ready to be sent?

})

app.post('/predict', function (req,res){
    darknet.stdin.write(user_input+'\n');

    res.render();
})
```

Comment: Is darknet data being sent to ALL connected users?  Or only to one that did the `app.post()`?   What if multiple users do an `app.post()`?  In order to associate a connected socket with a particular user, you will likely need to use a user session so when they connect, you can associate a socket with an http request.  This is a really broad question with lots of open ends in how you want your app designed.  Right now the darknet stuff appears to be global to your server which does not appear to be a multi-user design (e.g. a server that can independently serve the needs of many users).

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question, jfriend00.
The darknet data is being sent to the user that did app.post() only. 
The design that all users share a global darknet is intended, because I tested darknet
and found out that repeatedly started it will cause some error in CUDA (GOU stuff).
Yes, it is a problem if multiple users call app.post() and send input to darknet. 
However, a solution I have in mind is that from darknet output I can get the exact input value. This should solve the problem of associating darknet output to the correct input.

Comment: I think the main question is that from the darknet output, how do I get the user 
information? It seems that after user posted I have finished the communication 
with the user. The only information I recorded is probably a socket, but the socket, even I can store it in the user session, needs me to first get the user information back.

Comment: I have read through socket.io documentation. One idea I have it to use namespace or room
from socket.io. That is, I create a namespace for each connected client, remember the map between the user input and the space name, and when the darknet output is ready, broadcast the result to the corresponding namespace? Do you think this may work? Is this a misuse or abuse of socket.io namespace?
Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: You don't need to create a namespace.  Every connection already has a `socket.id` and already has a room created just for them and by just knowing that you can send to that socket.  But, this doesn't answer any of the bigger server architecture questions I asked in my earlier comments which is required before any further progress can be made.

Comment: Read about server-side user sessions (see the express-session module).  This allows you to save user-specific state on the server so that when the user connects again, you can have access to server-side data for that specific user.  You will need that in a number of ways here.  But, please read the first three questions in my first comment here and supply an answer to those.  That's a fundamental design question that we can really proceed without you coming up with an answer or without discussing that.

Comment: Is darknet data being sent to ALL connected users?

No.

Or only to one that did the app.post()? 

Yes, only to the user who did the app.post()

What if multiple users do an app.post()? 

Then the darknet data will be sent to the respective users. For example, assume that
we have two users: userA and userB. Also, assume they sent the inputA and inputB 
respectively to the server, which will send the data to darknet. In this case, the
outputA from darknet will be sent to userA and outputB to userB.

Comment: You mentioned about socket.id. Do you think I should store the mapping relation between the input and the socket.id, and once I got the output from darknet, I can indirectly get socket.id through the stored input value? The question is, from socket.id, can we get socket?

Comment: A more serious question is that the old socket.id may be invalidated (because a new socket may have been created due to the user page refresh) while darknet is performing the
computation. If this happens, then sending the result to the stored session does not seem to be right. Sorry, I do not have a good understanding of express/socket.io? Maybe I should read express-session first?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That's why whenever a client reconnects (makes a new socket connection), you have to update the user session so you always have stored the latest socket or socket.id.

Comment: From socket.id, you can get socket or you can just send directly to it with `io.to(socket.id).broadcast()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, jfriend00. I will keep my post updated along the way that I implement my application so that new comers may think it useful.

Comment: That's not how stack overflow works.  You don't continually update your question.  You ask a question, edit it to clarify, then people supply answers.  This is not like a blog.  You don't put answers in your question.  Questions are questions.  Answers are answers.  You can answer your own question if you want by posting an answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.